# How to find values that exist in both dataframes using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-2.7, analytics

I have 2 dataframes outlines below

df1 columns
a b c d

df2 columns
x y z

I want to find all x values that match with c (I do not have an ID to merge these columns)

Comment: Are the size of both dataframes same?

Comment: If both data frame has a same size  use :

`value_match = df2.loc[df2['x']==df['c'].values]['x']`

Comment: No the dataframes are different sizes

Answer (score 0):

the one approach that comes to mind if size did not match is :

> create the data frames for test:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9,20,25],[52, 28,77,96],[23, 19,220,2335],[234, 
                     93,420,2345],[234, 9434,220,245] ] , columns=['a', 'b','c','d'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9,15], [77,256,25],[220,58,63]], columns=['x', 'y','z'])
```

> Answer your question

```
def compare_values(a,b):
    # a and b are list of values in columns need to compare
    val = []
    for value in a :
        if value in b:
            val.append(value)
    return val
x = lambda a , b  : compare_values(a,b)
x(df['c'].values, df2['x'].values)
```

Comment: you can return `set`  if you don't need repetitive values